# Changing content with .change Jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well as the title says, I want to change (or add) text in "p" html tag, after I write something inside "input".I thought it would be simple, but somehow I can't get it to work. This is an example code:

test.php

```
<form>
<input id="text" class="text" />
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

test.js

```
$("form").change(function()
{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "asd";
});
```

I can't find the the error, although when I use:`$(document).change...` instead it works fine... I guess the problem is simple but I just keep missing it.

Comment: since you are already using jQuery you can get elements by id using the short form `$("#output")` and set its inner HTML element by using `$("#output").html('asd')` - related to the question, I don't think the form element changes (unless you add/remove an input).  Instead, the input element changes (i.e. when you type something, its value changes) so the 'trigger' should be associated with an element that changes

Comment: Yea I know, I just got used to use document.

Comment: Are you binding event once FORM is available in the DOM, not before? Your issue doesn't come from your posted code

Answer (score 2):

You must check for changes into the `input` element. Use the following code:

```
$("input").change(function() { 
    // your action
});
```

Comment: the change event will bubble to FORM level, see there: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrko22n/

Answer (score 1):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b1e2sfck/)

```
 $(".text").on('keyup',function()
    {
    $("#output").text( $(this).val());
   });
```

Comment: Should be: `$("form #text")...` at the start.

Comment: @Annabel take another look at html code  id="text" class="text"

Answer (score 0):

How are you?

If you want to listen the input change event, you have to subscribe the event to that input.

```
$("#text").change(function() {});
```

Or:

```
$("body").change("#text", function() {});
```

Also, if you want to listen while the user types, you can use:

```
$("#text").on("change keyup", function() {});
```

Or:

```
$("body").on("change keyup", "#text", function() {});
```

I hope that helps you.

Regards.